# How can we get data from any given url using javascript? not using any framework just simple javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a client-side software that will parse any form of data into it json form. But i have some difficulty in getting data from a url by using simple javascript?

Is this is the right way of using jQuery or not?

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                let URL = document.getElementById("URL");
                document.getElementById("urlClick").onclick = function 
                   httpGet(URL){
                    console.log(URL);
                    $.get('URL'+ name, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }   
            });
</script>
```

I expected the output of this given url:

```
<https://api.myjson.com/bins/m9d8b>`
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but why not just use `fetch`?

Comment: The title of your question asks for no framework, just simple javascript. But the body of your question seeks advice about the correct application of jQuery to your goal. That's a little confusing. However, taken as a whole I think you might find the shorthand method [$.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) helpful.